# Removing Image after some days?

Tags: javascript, html

Please help me with this.

Example i have the following code for the image and want the below image to get removed after 5 days, how to code it further ?

```
    <imgsrc="http://www.quackit.com/pix/milford_sound/milford_sound_t.jpg" style="max-width:100%" alt="Milford Sound in New Zealand" />
```

what code should be added to this code to make this image removed after 5 days ??

Comment: Don't use javascript.

Comment: Er… that's not an image.

Comment: what coding should be done for removing image after somedays and which script should be used ??

Comment: @Pary simply remove the whole block. The "image" as you call it is Google advertisement. those two javascript blocks are most likely responsible for the advertisement picture to show. removing those two blocks will likely remove the advertisement picture

Comment: seems more of a job for PHP...

Comment: I wasn't trying to be funy Pary. i tried to explain how to solve what i thought is your problem. The "image" is javascript generated. the code you posted in your query is what makes the image appear on the page therefore removing that code will remove that image. maybe if you could explain little more in detail why manual removal after 5 days will not do or 5 days from when it's to be removed then maybe there's better answer.

Comment: definite duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15453526/code-to-remove-image

Comment: @ Martina & All, yes dear i know its a google adsence code but i put it there just for reference, my question is as i have mentioned,Suppose i have i have 10 images placed on 10 different link so rather keeping it manually and remembering the dates, a coding will be better to get it removed....

Comment: In that case, could you include link to a page (that you possibly have somewhere online) where i could see what does google actually add to it? Then from looking at that someone may be able to come up with a solution.

Comment: Say the following is the image code                                    <imgsrc="http://www.quackit.com/pix/milford_sound/milford_sound_t.jpg" style="max-width:100%" alt="Milford Sound in New Zealand" />       So then how to set code to remove the image after say after 5 days ??

Comment: Please provide some link, JSFiddle, or code you have tried. Once again, we are not code-writers here to do your bidding.

Comment: Pary, i don't mind giving you some ideas or some simple code, but i am not able to answer from the info you are giving me. To do anything with it in JavaScript you will have to be able to identify the img within your document. the only way(right now) would be by the src parametre, but that is NOT constant and will be different everytime, so what you gave us is no use. i need to see your page, maybe it's always the LAST image on the page, then there would be solution to your problem. removing **that specific** picture you included will not work because the picture is likely different everytime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove any (1 or more) IMG tags of given URL:

```
<img src="http://quackit.com/pix/milford_sound/milford_sound_t.jpg"; 
    style="max-width:100%" alt="Milford Sound in New Zealand" />
```

from a page by JavaScript append the following code:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
function removeThatImg() {
    var ex=document.getElementsByTagName("img");
    for (var i=0;i<ex.length;i++) {
        if ( ex[i].src == "http://quackit.com/pix/milford_sound/milford_sound_t.jpg" )
            ex[i].parentNode.removeChild(ex[i]);
    }
}
var dateStart = Date.parse('March 16, 2013')/86400000;
var dateNow = new Date();
dateNow = dateNow.getTime()/86400000;
if ( dateNow - dateStart > 5) // more than 5 days 
    window.onload=function() {
        //do it with a half second delay, because google may take time to add that image
        //and right after the page is loaded it may not yet be there
        setTimeout(removeThatImg,500);
    }
</script>
```

it just MAY work (or may not - which i think will be the case, simply, because the image will be different everytime)

Comment: awesome awesome martina though i have not tried it yet but.... thanks for ur efforts, u r really a sweet-heart.....

Comment: Dear Martina, one more thing, i will not try this on google ads, i wanna make it happen to my contents, like images that i put on net or something like that.... i hope this helps, just to confirm, as i can read the code (though i am just a jejune, not proficient or expert like u) so do i need to specify some condition in the code or the code is all set to run ?? say if i need to set the image removal after 3 days then what r the fields i need to fill or update ?? also will the same script work on other image if i change the ex[i].src in the code ?? i hope u understand my stupid questions....

Comment: @Pary Hi Pary, I just tested the code and it runs ok. MAke sure to enter the URL (`src` parametre of the img tag and the same after `ex[i].src=` as `http://something.com/somthing/somthing.xxx` to avoid problems. To change the days, notice where it says: **dateNow - dateStart > 5)** that 5 in there is your amount of days. To make it remove another picture with another "src" replace that bit after `ex[i].src == "` but make sure that both the image and the code starts with `http://` (the way it's updated in the code above).

Comment: Hey Martina, Hows u ?? well once again Thanks for that, may i ask for one more help, if u could do.... can u code the same thing but this time for number of clicks, meaning the image should get removed or invisible say after 10 clicks.... for example (i put one image on my website and i want that the image should get removed after 10 click on that Img, may it take 20 days to get 10 clicks) the click should get stored so that after end of one session the click count should not get removed or not getting to zero again.... pls let me know if its not clear to you :-)

Comment: @Pary Hi, to do that you would have to use ajax calls to some server side script or you would have to pass through counter script on the way to where the image link would point to (assuming you would use it for image links - such as ads) in connection with database. Such code would be much more extensive than that above and would take quite longer to make and you have to realize that people here are not paid at all and have their own work and interests to do. Your best bet would be to hire someone for the job ideally local person whom you could meet and explain the whole thing properly.

Comment: Dear why r u shouting on me ?? :-( i already know & realize  that people here are for their hobby and interest, and not paid. That's why i ask for Help & i guess help is given for Free. I am a start-up and i don't have enough money to hire some proficient programmer like u nor i am good in programming, but after some time (may be in couple of years) i could be able to hire people like U or may be U.... wht i asked if it is a difficult program  or may be not under ur scope then its ok, Thanks for ur help my Friend....

Comment: @Pary It seems that you are too sensitive :) I wasn't shouting. Good you know all those things. First, you have to define your problem as precisely as you can ("how to remove picture after 10 cicks" isn't good enough, because this "subproblem" may not be needed for the job and in the end we will spend hours of our free time doing something that's of no use to anyone. I am willing to help you define your problem and develop some method how to go about solving it but i don't think i have the time for coding it. besides, if you know exactly what you're after, i'm sure the i-net is full of answers